# Why I get cannot be resolved with maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am building a Dropwizard project. 
(start with:https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/getting-started.html)

I create a project in eclipse, but don't understand why I get "cannot be resolved".

This is errors:
[image]

This is pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>foo.bar.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>mvn-test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>mvn-test</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <dropwizard.version>INSERT VERSION HERE</dropwizard.version>
  </properties>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
        <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Any one can help?
I don't know how to import the package, i really have no idea with maven dependency.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to insert your specific `dropwizard.version`:

```
<dropwizard.version>**INSERT VERSION HERE**</dropwizard.version>
```

so it can be used in your `pom`:

```
<version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to define ${dropwizard.version} tag between  in pom.xml like this :

```
<properties>
    <dropwizard.version>0.7.0</dropwizard.version>
</properties>
```